# How to change bootstrap inline datepicker to fit full width

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker from here: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Now I would like to fit it's width with the parent container, but at the moment it only fills a fixed size and I don't know where to change it via CSS. Maybe you've got an similar problem earlier and would like to help me?

I've attached a picture of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShZTU.png

And here's the code before adding the datepicker functionality via JavaScript:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">';
<div class="panel panel-success panel-dark widget-profile ">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="widget-profile-bg-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-flask"></i>
        </div>
        <img src="assets/demo/avatars/2.jpg" alt="" class="widget-profile-avatar">
            <div class="widget-profile-header">
                <span>Robert Jang</span>
                <br>
                        email@example.com
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / .panel-heading -->
            <div id="bs-datepicker-inline"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then I add the datepicker functionality with this JavaScript code:

```
 jQuery('#bs-datepicker-inline').datepicker();
```

And after this my final source code looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="panel panel-success panel-dark widget-profile ">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="widget-profile-bg-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-flask"></i>
        </div>
        <img src="assets/demo/avatars/2.jpg" alt="" class="widget-profile-avatar">
            <div class="widget-profile-header">
                <span>Robert Jang</span>
                <br>
                        email@example.com

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / .panel-heading -->
            <div id="bs-datepicker-inline">
                <div class="datepicker datepicker-inline">
                    <div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block;">
                        <table class=" table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">«</th>
                                    <th colspan="5" class="datepicker-switch">February 2015</th>
                                    <th class="next" style="visibility: visible;">»</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="dow">Su</th>
                                    <th class="dow">Mo</th>
                                    <th class="dow">Tu</th>
                                    <th class="dow">We</th>
                                    <th class="dow">Th</th>
                                    <th class="dow">Fr</th>
                                    <th class="dow">Sa</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="day old">25</td>
                                    <td class="day old">26</td>
                                    <td class="day old">27</td>
                                    <td class="day old">28</td>
                                    <td class="day old">29</td>
                                    <td class="day old">30</td>
                                    <td class="day old">31</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="day">1</td>
                                    <td class="day">2</td>
                                    <td class="day">3</td>
                                    <td class="day">4</td>
                                    <td class="day">5</td>
                                    <td class="day">6</td>
                                    <td class="day">7</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="day">8</td>
                                    <td class="day">9</td>
                                    <td class="day">10</td>
                                    <td class="day">11</td>
                                    <td class="day">12</td>
                                    <td class="day">13</td>
                                    <td class="day">14</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="day">15</td>
                                    <td class="day">16</td>
                                    <td class="day">17</td>
                                    <td class="day">18</td>
                                    <td class="day">19</td>
                                    <td class="day">20</td>
                                    <td class="day">21</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="day">22</td>
                                    <td class="day">23</td>
                                    <td class="day">24</td>
                                    <td class="day">25</td>
                                    <td class="day">26</td>
                                    <td class="day">27</td>
                                    <td class="day">28</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="day new">1</td>
                                    <td class="day new">2</td>
                                    <td class="day new">3</td>
                                    <td class="day new">4</td>
                                    <td class="day new">5</td>
                                    <td class="day new">6</td>
                                    <td class="day new">7</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Today</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="7" class="clear" style="display: none;">Clear</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none;">
                        <table class="table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">«</th>
                                    <th colspan="5" class="datepicker-switch">2015</th>
                                    <th class="next" style="visibility: visible;">»</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="7">
                                        <span class="month">Jan</span>
                                        <span class="month">Feb</span>
                                        <span class="month">Mar</span>
                                        <span class="month">Apr</span>
                                        <span class="month">May</span>
                                        <span class="month">Jun</span>
                                        <span class="month">Jul</span>
                                        <span class="month">Aug</span>
                                        <span class="month">Sep</span>
                                        <span class="month">Oct</span>
                                        <span class="month">Nov</span>
                                        <span class="month">Dec</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Today</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="7" class="clear" style="display: none;">Clear</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none;">
                        <table class="table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">«</th>
                                    <th colspan="5" class="datepicker-switch">2010-2019</th>
                                    <th class="next" style="visibility: visible;">»</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="7">
                                        <span class="year old">2009</span>
                                        <span class="year">2010</span>
                                        <span class="year">2011</span>
                                        <span class="year">2012</span>
                                        <span class="year">2013</span>
                                        <span class="year">2014</span>
                                        <span class="year">2015</span>
                                        <span class="year">2016</span>
                                        <span class="year">2017</span>
                                        <span class="year">2018</span>
                                        <span class="year">2019</span>
                                        <span class="year new">2020</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Today</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="7" class="clear" style="display: none;">Clear</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope someone could help me. Please let me know if you need some more information.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

Here's the CSS Code of the Datepicker

```css
.datepicker {
  direction: ltr;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto !important;
}
.datepicker.datepicker-inline {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.datepicker > div {
  display: none;
}
.datepicker.days div.datepicker-days,
.datepicker.months div.datepicker-months,
.datepicker.years div.datepicker-years {
  display: block;
}
.datepicker div.datepicker-months td,
.datepicker div.datepicker-years td {
  width: 210px !important;
}
.datepicker table {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.datepicker td {
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
.table-striped .datepicker table tr td,
.table-striped .datepicker table tr th {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.datepicker table tr td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
.datepicker table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.datepicker table tr td.day:hover {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.datepicker table tr td.old,
.datepicker table tr td.new {
  color: #bbb;
}
.datepicker table tr td.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td.disabled:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #eee;
  cursor: default;
}
.datepicker table tr td.today,
.datepicker table tr td.today:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.today.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td.today.disabled:hover {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}
.datepicker table tr td.today:hover:hover {
  color: #555555;
}
.datepicker table tr td.today.active:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.datepicker table tr td.range,
.datepicker table tr td.range:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.range.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td.range.disabled:hover {
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.datepicker table tr td.range.today,
.datepicker table tr td.range.today:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.range.today.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td.range.today.disabled:hover {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.datepicker table tr td.selected,
.datepicker table tr td.selected:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.selected.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td.selected.disabled:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.datepicker table tr td.active,
.datepicker table tr td.active:hover,
.datepicker table tr td.active.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td.active.disabled:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.datepicker table tr td span {
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 54px;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 23%;
}
.datepicker table tr td span:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
.datepicker table tr td span.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td span.disabled:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #eee;
  cursor: default;
}
.datepicker table tr td span.active,
.datepicker table tr td span.active:hover,
.datepicker table tr td span.active.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td span.active.disabled:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.datepicker table tr td span.old,
.datepicker table tr td span.new {
  color: #eee;
}
.datepicker thead tr:first-child th,
.datepicker tfoot tr th {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.datepicker th,
.datepicker td,
.datepicker tr {
  border-top: none !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}
.datepicker thead th,
.datepicker tfoot th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.datepicker thead th {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 35px !important;
  height: 35px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  text-align: center;
}
.datepicker thead tr:first-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid !important;
}
.datepicker thead tr:first-child th:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.datepicker thead tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
.datepicker thead th.prev,
.datepicker thead th.next {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 36px !important;
}
.datepicker thead th.prev:after,
.datepicker thead th.next:after {
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 36px;
}
.datepicker thead th.prev {
  left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
.datepicker thead th.prev:after {
  content: "\f053";
}
.datepicker thead th.next {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  right: 0;
}
.datepicker thead th.next:after {
  content: "\f054";
}
.datepicker tfoot th:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
.datepicker tbody td,
.datepicker tfoot th {
  line-height: 32px !important;
}
.datepicker > .datepicker-days tbody .cw {
  background: #f8f8f8 !important;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.datepicker > .datepicker-days thead tr:first-child th.cw {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: default;
}
.datepicker > .datepicker-days thead tr:first-child th.cw + .prev {
  left: 30px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
.datepicker > .datepicker-days thead tr:last-child th.cw + th {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This work for me:

```
.datepicker-inline {
    width: 100%;
}
.datepicker table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I needed to change .datepicker-inline to .datepicker.datepicker-inline with the node package "boostrap-sass-datepicker".

Answer (score 3):

This work for me:

```
<style>
.datetimepicker {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the line `Width:;` in the css of the datepicker and set it to inherit `width = inherit;` that should give it the with of the parent div. if that doesnt work please post your css code for the datepicker.

Comment: Hey EntangledQuantum, thank you for your response. I've already tried to edit the width in the css Code. So I have edited the .datepicker class to width: inherit but it doesn't worked. I've added the full css code at my post.

Comment: In `.datepicker table tr td span` set the width to `width= 100%;` if that doesnt work then remove all width arguments and see if it changes anything, if it does then remove every width argument seperately to find out which one keeps your datepicker from taking full width.

Comment: Hey EntangledQuantum, thank you again very much for your answer. I've tried to do it but it has no effect, the width stays smaller than the content of the panel allows.. do you have any other idea?

Comment: then its probably hardcoded into the datepicker.js file but i dunno js so i can't help you with that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Change the container and orientation in the init script:

```
$('#pay_date').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    container: '#pay_date1-group',
    orientation: "auto top"
});
```

The container must be its immediate parent element (it will be the width of whatever parent you specify)